# reset css (img)

Tags: css, html, image, css-reset

I am new in CSS so have a simple question.

here is my script =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Default</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <style type="text/css">
    body,div,html,img
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <img src="/project/pics/5.jpg" width="240" height="200">
          <img src="/project/pics/10.jpg" width="240" height="200">
          <img src="/project/pics/10.jpg" width="240" height="200">
      </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

So my question is that , despite of CSS reset between images are spaces, which of course cause some problems after styling layout, so anyone knows how to solve , how to reset CSS that there were not any spaces between images, Thanks ...

I guessed lol, it is really very simple , just it must be written  in one line , otherwise it must be declared font-size: 0;

Thanks all :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that happens is that the browser parses the linebreaks between images as spaces. Images are inline elements, and will have a literal space between them when a whitespace (or a linebreak) is used.

To eliminate the problem, either `float: left;` on the images, or simply eliminate the line breaks (as in, put them all on the same line, with no spaces between the tags).
Another solution is to set `font-size: 0;` on the parent, and then `font-size: 16px;` on the elements themselves.

Comment: I guessed , you are right :) , line-height: 0; removes spaces between above below images , but which property is use for side removing ?

Comment: @Tornike try setting the `font-size: 0px;` No need to set the line-height, this takes care of it.

Comment: @blackpla9ue thanks, it works , why it is so , can you explain ? :)

Comment: Because if the font-size is 0, that's also the size of the space. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: its because of the space left between the `img` tags. It works once you remove the white-spaces between the `img` tags. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Ktz7d/

Comment: @blackpla9ue: I think he meant the `font-size: 0` genius :)

Comment: Not to eliminate anything just write <img ...><img ...><img ...>... in one line :)

Answer (score 1):

For a full CSS reset use this instead

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Then float the image elements

```
img{
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but this doesn't gives any difference

Comment: write another rule for `img` to set `display:block;` or simply float them

Answer (score 1):

Try floating them left. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Peybv/)

Comment: How I know it is possible to solve this problem without mentioned, but I can not get it what I have missed in CSS script

Answer (score 1):

You can put the images contiguous:

```
  <div>
      <img src="/project/pics/5.jpg" width="240" height="200" /><img
           src="/project/pics/10.jpg" width="240" height="200" /><img
           src="/project/pics/10.jpg" width="240" height="200" />
  </div>
```

---

Or, you can do something (*that I don't consider a css reset*) to handle:

- [letter-spacing: -1em;](http://jsbin.com/ifigaf/2/edit#source)